# Can't get startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges working in iOS 5

Tags: ios, gps, location, core-location

I have a small issue with the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, it doesn't seem to work. the location icon is shown, but my delegate function is never triggered

I have made a class for it here it is:

header file:

```
@interface geolocation : NSObject < CLLocationManagerDelegate > {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
}

- (void) significantChange;
- (void) stopSignificantChange;
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

m file:

```
@implementation geolocation

- (void) significantChange
{
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void) stopSignificantChange
{
    [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                                        beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                                        }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{        
        UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (alarm)
        {
            alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
            alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
            alarm.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!";
            alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    });    
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void) dealloc 
{
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
    locationManager = nil;
}

@end
```

in AppDelegate I call it:

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [geo significantChange];
    return [super applicationDidEnterBackground:application];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're moving far enough? "Significant" might mean changing cell towers, for example.

Comment: Yep, I have been out driving 50 Kilometres, foursquare had no issue, neither had reminders.

Comment: did you have any logging code in the `didFailWithError` delegate method?  If not, it might be useful to add it.

Comment: Hmmm, I played around with and added the background mode for location in the plist, and then it works, but as I understood you don't need this when using significantChange, right?

Answer (score 0):

In my case "significant" means 11 callbacks in more than 60 km. So you might just be at the limit.

Edit: That is driving straight south. If you are just driving round and round it is very reasonable that nothing happens.

Comment: @TueTopholm - can you post here the solution to this problem? 
I have a similar problem of net getting location updates in ios 5.0.1 i wonder if it is the same problem.

Comment: @ItayLevin: You could possibly use startUpdatingLocation instead in conjunction with a distance filter. This, however, will still use a lot of power.

Comment: @tommyo - my problem is not the power or not.. i don't get any updates..something with the permission scema has changed between ios 4 and ios 5. what is working in 4 not working in 5.